# What does it take for a function written as a series to be smooth

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have a homework question where I basically need to find a
$\varphi$ function, so that

$f=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}a_n\varphi(t)t^n$ is smooth and its derivatives have certain values at a certain point.

My main problem is, I dont know how to differentiat this function to verify if my $\varphi$ works.

I do know that it can be differentiated piecewise, in the radius of convergence of $f$... but is this  actually a power series? What should I be certain of to conclude $f$ is firstly smooth and how can I take its derivative if it is so :)

---

Full homework question statement (**but I would really care to not get the complete answer**, rather a hint which allows me to work with):

> For every real sequence $(a_n)$ construct $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$
> with:
>
> $$\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(0)=a_n.$$
>
> Use $$f=\sum_{n\ge0}a_n\varphi((1+a_n^2)t)t^n$$
>
> with proper bump function $\varphi$.

---

First idea as solution:

Suppose $f(t):=\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k\varphi((1+a_k^2)t)t^k $ converges, then:

\begin{align*}
\\f^{(n)}(t)&=\partial^n \left ( \sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k\varphi((1+a_k^2)t)t^k\right )=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\partial ^n (a_k\varphi((1+a_k^2)t)t^k)\\
&=\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k \left(\sum^n_{s=0}\frac{n!}{s!(n-s)!}(\varphi((1+a_k^2)t))^{(n-s)}(t^k)^{(s)}\right)
\\
&=\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k \left(\sum^n_{s=0}\frac{n!}{s!(n-s)!}(1+a_k^2)^{n-s}\varphi^{(n-s)}((1+a_k^2)t)\frac{s!}{(k-s)!}t^{k-s}\right)
\\
:&=\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k B_k(t) 
\end{align*}

$\Longrightarrow  \forall k<n:B_k(0)=0,$ da $\forall s:\,t^{k-s}\equiv0$

For $k=n$ holds:

$$(1):B_k(0)=(1+a_n^2)^0\varphi^{(0)}(0)n!+B_{k-1}(0)=\varphi(0)n!$$

And now look at $k+1>n$:

$$B_{k+1}(0)=(1+a_{k+1}^2)\varphi^{(1)}(0)+B_{k-1}(0)+\varphi(0)\cdot 0=(1+a_{k+1}^2)\varphi^{(1)}(0)$$

which means we only need $\varphi(0)=1$ and $\varphi^{(n)}(0)=0, \forall n>0$. It would work with:

$$f(t):=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n\frac{e^{-(1+a_n^2)t}}{(-(1+a_n^2))^n}t^n$$

does this series converge? And how could I show it? I only know that if a power series convergence it defines a analytic function in the convergence radius. But how can I say something about for example this series? And I dont really know if Im even allowed to differentiate this series piecewise..

Comment: Could you be kind enough to edit your post to include the original problem statement? I think that'll make it easier to provide the help you seek :)

Comment: Every possible sequence is the Taylor series of a certain smooth $f$ by adjusting the summands correctly

Comment: I included the original problem, but I would really care to not get the complete answer, rather a hint which allows me to work with :)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma Does it help?

Comment: Well you can use the root test which works for arbitrary series, even if its not exactly a power series

Comment: I added your comment about hints into the question body to hopefully prevent a full solution from being posted. If you don't agree with what I did, you can edit to remove it

Comment: I edited my post with my first new try for a solution, maybe someone want to look over my attempt

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $\sum_n a_n t^n$, if the $a_n$ grow at most exponentially, then the Weierstrass M-test applies inside the radius of convergence, so you can differentiate term-by-term at $0$. However, if $a_n$ grows faster than exponentially (e.g. $a_n = n!$), everything blows up and you lose all control.

So, the idea is to tweak things by replacing $t^n$ with some variation which, near $t=0$, will decay quickly enough to offset the too-fast growth of $a_n$ and allow you to apply the M-test, to keep control over everything. You'll have to make sure your tweaks depend on the actual growth rate of $a_n$, so you'll want to use "more severe" tweaks when $a_n$ is especially large. The $1+a_n^2$ factor in $\varphi((1+a_n^2)t)$ serves this role well.

(Hopefully this is the sort of hint you were looking for.)

Comment: Ill try to put my work into progress with that information and come back later to tell if it was enough :) But it wasnt to much, thank you ;)

Comment: Hello I tried my best to get further :) (I edited my post with my attempt)

Comment: It's a good start. Don't get bogged down in picking an explicit bump function until and unless you absolutely have to. Your goal now is to show you can pick a bump function where the series passes the M-test (and then that the term-by-term derivatives have the same property). Consider the case when $a_n \to \infty$ is increasing for simplicity. Suppose the bump function is finitely supported. What does that say about which terms contribute to the sum for any given value of $t$? How large are those contributions?